# table size limit of postgresql under virtualbox

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu, virtualbox

Under Windows 10, The Ubuntu 20.04 was installed under the Oracle virtual box. The Postgresql 12.2 was installed under Ubuntu. When I try to create table with random data (31 day data with one day about 5M rows), the Python log file shows finished (slow from day 24). But in table only partial data there.

I googled and didn't find similar issue before...

Information of disk partition (835G out of 891G are free mounted on /var):

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~$ df -H
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                     34G     0   34G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   6.8G  3.1M  6.8G   1% /run
/dev/sda5               100G  8.7G   86G  10% /
tmpfs                    34G  8.2k   34G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   5.3M  4.1k  5.3M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                    34G     0   34G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda6               9.0G  3.5G  5.0G  41% /home
/dev/sda7               891G   11G  835G   2% /var
/dev/loop2              253M  253M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24
```

The Python log shows slow starting from loading 24-th day data:

```
[I 200525 16:10:38 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-01 data...
[I 200525 16:11:25 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-02 data...
[I 200525 16:12:10 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-03 data...
[I 200525 16:12:56 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-04 data...
[I 200525 16:13:45 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-05 data...
[I 200525 16:14:31 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-06 data...
[I 200525 16:15:19 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-07 data...
[I 200525 16:16:04 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-08 data...
[I 200525 16:16:50 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-09 data...
[I 200525 16:17:37 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-10 data...
[I 200525 16:18:24 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-11 data...
[I 200525 16:19:10 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-12 data...
[I 200525 16:19:58 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-13 data...
[I 200525 16:20:44 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-14 data...
[I 200525 16:21:29 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-15 data...
[I 200525 16:22:16 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-16 data...
[I 200525 16:23:02 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-17 data...
[I 200525 16:23:48 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-18 data...
[I 200525 16:24:33 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-19 data...
[I 200525 16:25:23 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-20 data...
[I 200525 16:26:09 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-21 data...
[I 200525 16:26:59 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-22 data...
[I 200525 16:27:47 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-23 data...
[I 200525 16:31:38 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-24 data...
[I 200525 16:38:48 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-25 data...
[I 200525 16:51:38 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-26 data...
[I 200525 17:02:07 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-27 data...
[I 200525 17:14:26 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-28 data...
[I 200525 17:28:36 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-29 data...
[I 200525 17:44:28 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-30 data...
[I 200525 18:09:19 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-31 data...
[I 200525 18:28:45 startpoint:43] end python code
```

The resultant records in the table generated:

```
dbhuge=> select substr(tid::text,1,6) as dt, count(*) from tbl_huge group by 1 order by 1;
   dt   |  count  
--------+---------
 190107 | 2769655
 190108 | 5624951
 190109 | 3533726
 190121 |   91628
 190123 | 3733923
 190124 | 5863851
 190125 | 5777633
 190126 | 5759523
 190127 | 5764017
 190128 | 5694689
 190129 | 5745608
 190130 | 5759871
 190131 | 5746663
(13 rows)

dbhuge=>
```

The final table size is only 5GB:

```
dbhuge=> SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size('tbl_huge') );
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 4984 MB
(1 row)

dbhuge=>
```

## Any suggestions are appreciated!

Thanks @pifor suggestion. The part of the log file shows below. Comparing with above Python log, when run normally, about "max_wal_size" hint lines are printed to log. During the weird behavior time 16:31-18:28, no log entry at all.

```
2020-05-25 16:27:32.946 PDT [145406] LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (27 seconds apart)
2020-05-25 16:27:32.946 PDT [145406] HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "max_wal_size".
2020-05-25 16:28:00.243 PDT [145406] LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (28 seconds apart)
2020-05-25 16:28:00.243 PDT [145406] HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "max_wal_size".
2020-05-25 19:31:31.650 PDT [234294] sinnud@dbhuge ERROR:  relation "tbl_huge" does not exist at character 51
```

## Close it now.

Thanks my colleague's suggestion. I kicked off rerun and this time it looks fine:

```
[I 200526 19:09:10 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-01 data...
[I 200526 19:10:58 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-02 data...
[I 200526 19:14:51 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-03 data...
[I 200526 19:23:51 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-04 data...
[I 200526 19:31:47 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-05 data...
[I 200526 19:41:21 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-06 data...
[I 200526 19:52:35 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-07 data...
[I 200526 20:06:06 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-08 data...
[I 200526 20:21:23 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-09 data...
[I 200526 20:38:54 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-10 data...
[I 200526 21:01:23 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-11 data...
[I 200526 21:21:10 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-12 data...
[I 200526 21:43:05 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-13 data...
[I 200526 22:07:12 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-14 data...
[I 200526 22:37:34 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-15 data...
[I 200526 23:05:16 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-16 data...
[I 200526 23:44:49 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-17 data...
[I 200527 00:16:11 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-18 data...
[I 200527 00:49:24 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-19 data...
[I 200527 01:24:27 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-20 data...
[I 200527 02:07:36 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-21 data...
[I 200527 02:46:30 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-22 data...
[I 200527 03:27:16 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-23 data...
[I 200527 04:10:05 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-24 data...
[I 200527 04:53:41 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-25 data...
[I 200527 05:38:31 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-26 data...
[I 200527 06:25:08 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-27 data...
[I 200527 07:13:25 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-28 data...
[I 200527 08:03:33 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-29 data...
[I 200527 08:55:29 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-30 data...
[I 200527 09:50:47 startpoint:22] Start loading 2019-01-31 data...
[I 200527 10:47:08 startpoint:43] end python code startpoint.py.
```

Now I have:

```
 df -H
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                     34G     0   34G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   6.8G  3.1M  6.8G   1% /run
/dev/sda5               100G  8.7G   86G  10% /
tmpfs                    34G  8.2k   34G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   5.3M  4.1k  5.3M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                    34G     0   34G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda6               9.0G  3.5G  5.0G  41% /home
/dev/sda7               891G   21G  826G   3% /var
/dev/loop2              253M  253M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/24
```

And

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size('tbl_huge') );
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 14 GB
(1 row)
```

It was slow because VM need to request 14GB space from host (Windows 10).
I think the first time run didn't finish successfully because postgresql configuration have issue when I tried to open port 5432. That was fixed yesterday. This the run last night looks good.

Thanks everyone's inputs!

Comment: There are some limits for a table size (32 TB) but this is not your case. Did you check PostgreSQL log file for any error ?

Comment: How yo uacces to database (which lib)? How do you handle transactions? Aren't your data in Python kept in memory (check Python memory usage)?

Comment: @Tupteq All data are randomly generated in database using generate_series (for number of rows) and random()::text for value of columns. Python just pass day, time, etc. to database. Not real data loading from Python to database.

Comment: I didn't mean you load data, but maybe you keep generated data in memory, consuming available RAM space. Maybe your generated data isn't garbage collected and at certain moment program starts using swap space. Also, if you put all data in one transaction, you may consider splitting it into smaller ones.

Comment: @Tupteq Maybe I didn't understand what you said... Based on my colleague's suggestion, I just rerun my code. When the code is running, I can check the table: ```dbhuge=> select substr(tid::text,1,6) as yymmdd, count(*) from tbl_huge
dbhuge-> group by 1 order by 1;
 yymmdd |  count  
--------+---------
 190101 | 5749963
 190102 | 5777655
 190103 | 5918907
 190104 | 5688902
 190105 | 5817937
 190106 | 5759991
 190107 |   25132
(7 rows)``` This mean, data is increasing...